# Android recording app, recording doesn't begin

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to java/Android and have been having trouble with a simple recording app.
I have been following this tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audio_capture.htm) and while I think I am at the end, my app does not work. Here is my .java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaRecorder audioRecorder;
    private String outFile = null;
    private Button record, stop, play;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        record = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);

        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(false);
        outFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myRec.3gp";

        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.reset();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFile(outFile);

    }

    public void record(View view){
        try {
            audioRecorder.prepare();
            audioRecorder.start();
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException ise){
            ise.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        record.setEnabled(false);
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void stop(View view){
        audioRecorder.stop();
        audioRecorder.release();
        audioRecorder = null;
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recorded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void play(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(outFile);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I have already made sure to include the proper uses-permissions in my xml file for external storage and recording audio.

When I run the app, I don't get any warnings, but I press the record button and nothing happens.  Can anyone help me see anything glaring that I have overlooked? Thanks so much!

I am using win7 with Android Studio and testing on a Motorola Moto G w/ Android 4.4.

Comment: have u added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: Did you set the record button to call your `record` method?

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar yes, I caught that one.

Comment: @immibis what is the best way for me to do that? just by using onClick? Ah that was totally it! I'm such a noob, thanks so much.

Comment: have u got this Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: i got u r geting NPE becoude u have not this outFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myRec.3gp";

Comment: use this code http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/voice-recording-in-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question with the code just for completeness, but all credit goes to immibis who is the one who directed me there.

I simply had not set the buttons to do anything on click. So I needed to change my xml to call the methods on click.  I added this line to each button in the xml (where record is the method name).

```
android:onClick="record"
```

Thanks again to immibis for the help on this.